# Opensource library to save tree of java objects to db or file

Tags: java, serialization, nosql, object-oriented-database

I am looking for an opensource library which can be used to transparently save java objects(and their dependencies!) to file or db, a kind of snapshot.

Sample use case: I have the state of a game in a bunch of objects, player, score, location etc. User clicks "save" and now I need to save these objects(all of the objects to be saved can be annotated) to a file or db. If system crashes or user log's in later, I should be able to recover from this point on.

I am looking for a library that can do it as transparently and efficiently as possible. Transaction etc is not necessary.
My priorities would be

1. OpenSource, free, Good documentation
2. Ease of use. User should
   not have to manually save the object after something is modified. Of
   if (s)he has to, it should be trivial activity
3. Stable
4. Should
   be easy to read from snapshot and recover.

Does a library exist that covers all 4 or at least a good portion of the above req's? I am opent to aspect oriented approaches

Am I asking the wrong q for my usecase? Is it done very differently in the industry?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard java serialization mechanism. If all your classes that you want to save implement tag interface `Serializable` you can transparently save as big as you want graph of objects. It is not DB, it is file, but you can always read these objects back to your application and probably it is the best (or the first) option for you.

The disadvantage of this method is that the data is binary, i.e. you cannot read it using Notepad. And format is very sensitive to changes done in classes, so support of backwards/forward compatibility is problematic.

Other possibility is to serialize objects as XML or JSON. For XML try JAXB or XStream. For JSON take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

Comment: JSon seems to be a good option. Can I save this kind of graph into a nosql db, say mongodb and then read it back fast. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the built in serialization of java to solve this. If you want it to save automatically, wrap your model in a layer which saves it for you. This could even be done "automatically" using proxies (java.lang.reflect.Proxy).

However, I usually do not recommend automatically saving state as values often are related. Imagine a progress class which keeps track of which level you are on and how far within that level you have gotten (say 0%, 25%, 50% and 75%).

Now, you are just completing level 2 so the progress has to be updated to "Level 3, 0%". If you first set the level the progress will (for a short period) have the state "Level 3, 75%" which is incorrect, and if you set how far first you will get "Level 2, 0%". Should the program stop at either of those points, then the user will have an incorrect state.

Comment: Is that the way it is done in java game servers? Serialize the object graph, save it (manually). Re-load it.

Comment: The state is serialized in some way, either by some built in mechanism or some other logic (for stability I think the latter is more common).

What you you mean by "manually" saving it? It does not have to be the user pressing a save button, it could be that your program saves state every x minutes or doing specific tasks in the game. 

Why do you need to reload it? (I can understand saving it as you go, and loading it if you want to get to an older state, but save-reload it immediate?)

Comment: I do not want to reload it immediate. By manual I actually meant programmer has to code the saving part manually after each update to POJO. Instead of it being transparently handled by aop or some such solution. But like you said, that may lead to inconsistent state and was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is an build-in-functionality called ObjectInput/ObjectOutput-Stream.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

If you like to have human-readable file's you may like to use XStream.

http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html